# Sharp rise in visitor numbers - any reason?

Tags: discussion

I was pleasantly surprised a couple of weeks ago when I noticed that the visitor numbers seemed to shoot up rather quickly from the steady 800-900 we'd been seeing gradually increase for a while, to the current number just shy of 1300. Much as this is a great thing, I'm curious - does anyone know a particular reason for this rise, or is it just part of us "taking off"? (which would be nice!)

Comment: I suspect it's seasonal, primarily warm weather on the US east coast and getting near Memorial day, the unofficial start of summer here in the US.

Comment: Me refreshing every 10 minutes?

Comment: @ppl Hopefully the algorithm is cleverer than that!

Answer (score 8):

The influx of new visitors is not consistent with a specific-question spike. But your new-found popularity corresponds almost perfectly with a similar increase on our [Gardening & Landscaping site](http://gardening.stackexchange.com). This seems to be a seasonal spike — an increase in outdoor interests corresponding to the arrival of warmer weather in the northern hemisphere.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no obvious spikes around a particular question, then it's likely to be the combination of increased interest as we get closer to summer in the northern hemisphere (where 88% of the world's population live) and one of those kinks in the curve we see as sites seem to break some unknown attendance barrier.

They are definitely a worthwhile sign that the right things are happening - but it would be interesting to see how seasonal the graph is for this site as opposed to others. Will we get a slump at the end of August; do we have a nice skipe in winter questions; etc?