# The condition of The Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion

I've looked recently to the statistics: http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday and our site was on the last place. Now it's a bit higher, but still it's much less than 1 question for day.

What is happening with the site? I hope it's not going to die. The winter was extremely long this year, but now it's finally over so the outdoor season have started. Why the activity on the site has not started with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, our questions/day is low, but all our other Area 51 statistics are doing well, and [our traffic has just started rising](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/369/18), so we should be safe for a while yet. Hopefully this rise in traffic will lead to a rise in questions soon, but you can help out by posting questions of your own and letting other people know about the site.